# IP of my site in the shared hosting got changed and did not reflect yet. what will be the SEO concequence?

Tags: seo, ip-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Effect on Google rankings if my site is down?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13914/effect-on-google-rankings-if-my-site-is-down)

My hosting company changes IP in the range of 6 months... May be either the change the servers or the IP. So for the past 20 hours my site is not loading in my place (India) where as i checked with my friend by that time in Japan. He said that it is loading there. But here it is still not.

The hosting company said that it will take max of 24-48 hours for propagation of DNS settings.

So at this time when google webmasters and google search bots and google crawl bots access the site what will happen.

Will this affect my SEO records in google? like not found or not reachable or network error?

Each countries ISP would be updating the dns in their own order so when japan got updated india did not (my service provider is Barthi Broadband (Airtel India)) .

I am unable to get into a conclusion.

**Besides is this related to Up Stream and Down Stream?**

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Besides is this related to Up Stream and Down Stream?" Are you talking about bandwidth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downtime does not affect your rankings. Pagerank is based only on incoming links. However, excessive downtime may get your site temporarily removed from Google altogether until it comes back up again.

Matt Cutts on [Can a site's downtime affect its ranking?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXrwyTGOf1E&feature=player_embedded) [YouTube, 1:21 onwards]:

> "If your website is down for a relatively small amount of time -- you know, a day or two -- then just bringing it back should mean that it pops right back into the search results, or it won't disappear at all. But at the point where your website is down for several days, or a week, or a month, then - yeah -- we probably are going to drop it from the search results, at least until we can fetch again, find it, index it, and return it."

In short, you don't need to do anything except wait. You may like to point your DNS records to your hosting company's nameservers instead of a fixed IP address to prevent the downtime should they switch IP addresses again, though.

Answer (score 2):

The google bot will come back another time, it won't just give up because it got one failure. However if you think it has affected your ranking you can [request reconsideration](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35843).