# What is the tolerable Website Downtime and it's Impact on SEO?

Tags: seo, web-hosting, downtime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Effect on Google rankings if my site is down?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13914/effect-on-google-rankings-if-my-site-is-down)

I'm using hostgator shared hosting for some of my sites and uptime reported by mo.ni.tor.us is in between 97% to 94%. Is it a tolerable range for downtime ? Also i would like to know how much downtime percentage is considered as okay in case of SEO ? I see that most updated blogs needs to have more uptime. But not sure how much downtime factor is considered in case of SEO ?

Comment: Also see http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15059/ip-of-my-site-in-the-shared-hosting-got-changed-and-did-not-reflect-yet-what-wil specifically http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXrwyTGOf1E&feature=player_embedded

Comment: Not interested in google ranking and all. Just interested in opinion of other webmasters on how much downtime and uptime is tolerable, along with opinion of how it affects bots, be it any search engine and aggregators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The less your downtime is the better. As for affect of your website due to the downtime [this](http://dejanseo.com.au/effect-of-website-downtime-on-rankings/) may help.

Comment: I'm getting 94-97% uptime. Do you think it's tolerable ? Or should i talk to hostgator support team about this ?

Comment: Personally... It's tolerable as long as it is not affecting the bottom line.