# Transferred hosting and website not online during transition for 2 weeks - will this affect search results?

Tags: seo, web-hosting, ranking

If a website's hosting is being transferred and is not online in between for approx. 14 days - would this affect the organic search positions when it's finally transferred? When they've since disappeared entirely from the search results?

NOT A DUPLICATE.

Comment: To avoid further disappointment please check out our [help center](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help). In addition you will find several questions and answers regarding newly purchased domains using redirects or without.

Comment: Why isn't this a duplicate?

Comment: @EDK678 I had read your question thoroughly, current as its stands it's still duplicate as there is many questions like it i.e with current edit it stands as a duplicate of http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13914/effect-on-google-rankings-if-my-site-is-down as well as other questions and answers regarding being removed from the index. Additionally please do not address the moderators on the site using edits on question titles.